# drawBitmap is not fullscreen

Tags: android, image, fullscreen, ondraw

I display an image using onDraw Method like this :

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);
     Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.photo0);
     canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
     canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
```

I want to set this image as background, but it is displayed only on a part of the screen. How to set it as fullscreen?

There is a way to set the image as background from xml and to draw other images on this image from onDraw Method?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try this:

```
...
Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
canvas.drawBitmap(background, null, dest, paint);
```

This renders a part of the bitmap ("null" means the whole bitmap) to the screen area specified by dest (which is the whole area of the view in this case).

Note that this will/might change the aspect ratio, depending on the background, you might need to fix that.

Comment: This change the quality of the image. If I set the image as background from xml it looks ok, but like this it is not clear

Comment: To fix the quality, create a Paint object and call setFilterBitmap(true). This will replace the default "nearest neighbour" sampling to "linear".

Comment: Did this but the image still filling only portion of the larger canvas.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me.

```
      WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width=size.x;
    int height= size.y;

    Rect dest = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bm, null, dest, paint); //bm is your bitmap
```

Comment: Can you explain why the question code was not working?

Comment: Because the bitmap was not drawing based on the screen size of device. First we have to take the resources of device to draw bitmap, like width and height.
Up vote if my answer helped you.

Comment: On the answer I meant ^_^